# sql command removed all my post_content and replaced it with urls

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I ran this sql command as was trying to put a slash after domain.com so image urls worked when moving a wordpress website between domains and now all the post_content fields are just urls?

like this

http://domain.com?page_id=7

Any ideas why this happened or any way to change it back?

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, "domain.comwp-content", "domain.com/wp-content");
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, your replace command looks fine. Did you maybe do one where you forgot the `post_content` in the replace call? That's happened to me... anyway, there will probably be no way to change it back except from a database backup. mySQL doesn't have "undo" functionality I'm afraid

Comment: Ok thanks for the input, hopefully I have cron job otherwise its time to get pasting

Comment: r u using JDBC drivers